# Assign id within a php echoed statement

Tags: javascript, php, html

in the below php statement I want to assign ID to EmployeeName.I will use the ID tag to search an element in the echoed list by name.Where am I making the mistake ?

```html
<?php  while( $toprow4 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt4) ) {

        echo  "<div class='parent-div'><span class='rank'>" . $toprow4['rank'] . "</span><span class='name'>" id = ' . $toprow4['EmployeeName'] .' "</span><span class='points'>" . $toprow4['pointsRewarded'] . "</span></div>";

      } ?>
```

Comment: How about define the var within javascript-content `<script>var id=xya;</script>` and not as plain html output?

Comment: too lazy to debug 1 line of code? nice. You forgot a concatenation (.), also you keep changing between singlequotes and doublequotes which makes it really annoying to read

Comment: You never said what error you were getting or anything, but you are not concatenating you string properly.

Comment: `Where am I making the mistake ?` You dont really now how html, php and javascript are working together.

Comment: Why do you not just make a `$id =  $toprow4['EmployeeName'];`before the echo?

Comment: @jane: Your code not clean, thats no reason do downvote all answers that are correct.

Comment: Actually, these answers are a wast of bytes as well. Question should be closed and deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Add the id to the div element as an `attribute` and not as `textContent`

```
echo  "<div class='parent-div' id='" . $toprow4['EmployeeName'] . "'><span class='rank'>" . $toprow4['rank'] . "</span><span class='name'>" . $toprow4['EmployeeName'] . "</span><span class='points'>" . $toprow4['pointsRewarded'] . "</span></div>";
```

and try and make that name a valid ID by removing spaces or replace them by `-`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your quotes. If you aren't already, I'd strongly recommend using an editor with code highlighting.

```
<?php
while ($toprow4 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt4)) {  
    $rank = $toprow4['rank'];
    $id = $toprow4['EmployeeName'];
    $points = $toprow4['pointsRewarded'];
    echo "<div class='parent-div'><span class='rank'>$rank</span>";
    echo "<span class='name' id='$id'></span><span class='points'>$points<span></div>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Why the downvote? For providing help here? Or is something wrong with my answer?

Comment: Are you sure the OP did this? I can't see who downvoted me.

Comment: @mtizziani I havenot downvoted any answer till now.But will downvote yours now.you will see the change .

Comment: @ChrisG thanks for the input.I am looking for something else.This seems correct though.

Comment: @ChrisG I got a downvote on my answer too. Don't get why people would downvote an answer without them reading it. But since the downvotes this question got, no wonder that people downvote its answers as well. I always get angry when someone just downvotes you with no explanation.

Comment: @jane Well, what *are* you looking for? Anyway, using the method I pointed out, you can easily insert PHP variables into strings without tons of quotes and dots.

Comment: Yeah..Thanks a lot. I found a solution myself.@ChrisG

Comment: Now I will upvote all the answers>just for the effort..!!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a big problem escaping your output string correctly. Perhaps you should to try write it clean by using templates and `sprintf()` like in this sample.

i did not test the logic of the while statement you have given

```
<?php
  $template  = '<div class="parent-div">';
  $template .= '<span class="rank">%s</span>';
  $template .= '<span class="name">id = %s</span>';
  $template .= '<span class="points">%s</span>';
  $template .= '</div>';

  while($toprow = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt4) {
    echo sprintf(
      $template, 
      $toprow['rank'], 
      $toprow['EmployeeName'], 
      $toprow['pointsRewarded']
    )
  }
?>
```

Your code is not clean, so you failed on making correct quotes and single-quotes.

Comment: be decent to others.We all seek help here.Ur code is correct>i am looking for something else.